# Can Per-deployment Logging work together with Logging sub system for Jboss EAP 6.4?

Tags: logging, jboss, wildfly, redhat, jboss-eap-6

I have multiple wars running on a standalone jboss server. I have logging subsystem configured in the standalone.xml. I referred 
[this redhat link on Add Per-deployment Logging to an Application](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Development_Guide/sect-Per-deployment_Logging.html) to create a log handler specific for one of the apps.

I created **logging.properties** file in the app war under META-INF folder with following content

```
loggers=com.company

logger.com.company.level=TRACE
logger.com.company.useParentHandlers=true
logger.com.company.handlers=TESTFILE

# A handler configuration
handler.TESTFILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler
handler.TESTFILE.level=TRACE
handler.TESTFILE.formatter=PATTERN1
handler.TESTFILE.properties=append,autoFlush,enabled,suffix,fileName
handler.TESTFILE.constructorProperties=fileName,append
handler.TESTFILE.append=true
handler.TESTFILE.autoFlush=true
handler.TESTFILE.enabled=true
handler.TESTFILE.fileName=${jboss.server.log.dir}/app.log

# The formatter to use
formatter.PATTERN1=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.PATTERN1.properties=pattern
formatter.PATTERN1.constructorProperties=pattern
formatter.PATTERN1.pattern=%d %-5p %c: %m%n
```

I deployed the app but it didn't do anything apart from what is configured in standalone.xml logging sub system. Is this setup supposed to work on EAP 6.4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this should work in JBoss EAP 6.4. You may want to try moving the logging.properties file to the `WAR/WEB-INF/classes`. There may have been a bug where it fails to look in the `WAR/WEB-INF` directory.

If that doesn't work you could also turn on trace logging for `org.jboss.as.logging` which should show the logging.properties file being found in your deployment.

The following CLI command will enable trace logging to see the details of what the logging subsystem is doing.

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as.logging:add(level=TRACE)
```

If you want to see these log messages on the console you'll need to enable trace logging for the console tool.

```
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=level, value=TRACE)
```

Comment: @james-r-perkins, Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion. I moved the file under /classes and it is now getting picked up. 
I see "14:10:22,075 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.logging] (MSC service thread 1-2) Found logging configuration file: "/C:/Java/jboss/bin/ ...." on the console. However the logging is still not working as expected. Now nothing form com.company gets logged anywhere. If I remove the property file, it is showing INFO messages on console and server.log.  I also noticed that com.company is not appearing on the generated logging.properties in the loggers=xx.xx.xx .. line.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the application is using slf4j and not jboss logger

Comment: That's fine. The `logging.properies` posted should be working. How are your loggers defined? Do you do something like `LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.company")?

Comment: package com.company.app.interceptor;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class....private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppIntreceptor.class);
 public boolean preHandle(.....){
  logger.debug("request directed to " + request.getParameter("Program"));
 }

Comment: I see that even if I placed an empty logging.properties file under classes folder, logging stops working for that particular app

Comment: I think I may see the error now actually. Try removing the `CONSOLE` from the `logger.com.company.handlers` property. You don't have one defined so it may be producing an error when configuring the log manager.

Comment: Did that, but still no logs. The TRACE on console shows the property file is found. I also assumed that the logger setup would cascade and if I have an empty logging.properties inside the app, logging should work as per the sub system settings in the standalone.xml. isnt that the case?

Comment: No that's not how it works unfortunately. When you have a logging.properties file a new log context gets created and nothing is inherited.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. Following that logic , I added the line loggers=com.company to the top (updated the question). Now it is creating app.log but with no contents.

Comment: Okay so you're closer then. Try adding a line like `logger.handlers=TESTFILE` and `logger.level=INFO` to see if you get anything in the file.

Comment: Yes That worked. I have setup 2 handlers for two packages and set the log level as INFO. I will update the latest code as the answer. One glitch I am seeing is the INFO messages from org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory gets logged to both logs when I expect it to go only to APPLOG

Comment: That does seem a bit weird. Not sure why that would happen.

Comment: I also found another weird issue. Everything works good in my local machine. When I deploy to my dev box APPLOG.log and INTERCEPTLOG.log get swapped. If I redeploy it get fixed randomly. and at times all logs goes to only one file. How do I debug this deeper?

Comment: Do you by chance have multiple config files? I can't think of a reason that would happen.

Comment: Yes. I have 3 apps on jboss and each of them has one logging.properties. I also noticed that the periodic logger logs to the logname with yesterday's date right now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to @James R Perkins for his answer and comments

here is the final configuration that worked

```
loggers=com.company.a,com.company.b.interceptor.app

logger.level=INFO
logger.handlers=APPLOG

logger.com.company.a.level=INFO
logger.com.company.a.useParentHandlers=false
logger.com.company.a.handlers=APPLOG

logger.com.company.b.interceptor.app.level=INFO
logger.com.company.b.interceptor.app.useParentHandlers=false
logger.com.company.b.interceptor.app.handlers=INTERCEPTLOG

# A handler configuration
handler.APPLOG=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.APPLOG.level=INFO
handler.APPLOG.formatter=PATTERN
handler.APPLOG.properties=append,autoFlush,enabled,suffix,fileName
handler.APPLOG.constructorProperties=fileName,append
handler.APPLOG.append=true
handler.APPLOG.autoFlush=true
handler.APPLOG.enabled=true
handler.APPLOG.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.APPLOG.fileName=${jboss.server.log.dir}/APPLOG.log

handler.INTERCEPTLOG=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.INTERCEPTLOG.level=INFO
handler.INTERCEPTLOG.formatter=PATTERN
handler.INTERCEPTLOG.properties=append,autoFlush,enabled,suffix,fileName
handler.INTERCEPTLOG.constructorProperties=fileName,append
handler.INTERCEPTLOG.append=true
handler.INTERCEPTLOG.autoFlush=true
handler.INTERCEPTLOG.enabled=true
handler.INTERCEPTLOG.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.INTERCEPTLOG.fileName=${jboss.server.log.dir}/INTERCEPTLOG.log

# The formatter to use
formatter.PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.PATTERN.properties=pattern
formatter.PATTERN.constructorProperties=pattern
formatter.PATTERN.pattern=%d %-5p %c: %m%n
```